# Library relies on another library

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have `RestClientLibrary` and `UserFunctionsLibrary`

`UserFunctionsLibrary` needs `RestClientLibrary` in order to function.

When I compile these down to `libRestClientLibrary.a` and `libUserFunctionsLibrary.a` how will they be able to interact with each other?

In Xcode currently I have set the `User header search paths` to find the .h files and I have linked the `UserFunctionsLibrary` with the `RestClientLibrary` binary. However, when distributed other users of these libraries may have different set ups and such. I can't see that it will work.

Thanks for any insight you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those .a files are just library files. They will need to be linked together to actually be used. The linker will handle resolving all the symbols from RestClientLibrary into UserFunctionsLibrary.

As far as other users, they will have to configure their system in a way such that both libraries are passed to the linker.

Comment: So an another dev has two folders `UserFunctionsLibrary` and `RestClientLibrary`. In these folders is an `.a` file and various `.h` files. The just need to link both of those libraries to their project and they will be able to communicate between each other too?

Comment: Correct. The linker will pull in all the symbols and functions it needs, but you need to point out where those files are to it.